# How to prevent '__return_true' used inside a wordpress shortcode from echoing "1"?

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode

Here is the part of the code that is problematic:

```
$found = false;

foreach ($posts as $post) {
  if ( stripos( $post->post_content, '[' . $shortcode ) !== false ) {

    add_shortcode( $shortcode, '__return_true' );
      $found = true;
    break;
    }
 }

  if ( $found )
    add_action('wp_head', $callback_function );

  return $posts;
}
```

Shortcode is doing what I want (bar at the top), but it is also displaying "1" on the post. I think it is because of the __return_true function. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use [`__return_false`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_return_false) or other utility function.
 `__return_true` specifically is interpreted as `1`, all this others not:

- `__return_zero()`
- `__return_null()`
- `__return_empty_string()`